# How to apply CSS even though my files are in the same directory?

Tags: html, css

I cannot seem to understand why my CSS is not being applied. The CSS file is in the same directory as the HTML file and compiles successfully.

Here is the directory for both:

**home.html**

```
C:\Users\topp003\Desktop\node projects\.vscode\home.html
```

**home.css**

```
C:\Users\topp003\Desktop\node projects\.vscode\home.css
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Introducing CSS</title>
        <link href="home.css" type="text/css"
        rel="stylesheet" />       
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>From Garden to Plate</h1>
        <p>A <i>potager</i> is a french term for an 
        ornamental vegtable or kitchen garden...</p>
        <h2>What to Plant</h2>
        <p>Plants are chosen as much for their functionality as a for their
            color and form...</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
h1, h2 {
    color: #ee3e80;
}
p {
    color: #665544;
}
```

Comment: Try putting a forward slash in the beginning of the href, i.e. “/home.css”

Comment: Use <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./home.css"  /> instead.
Note **./home.css**

Comment: @Akaqlonist I tried that change and it still won't apply

Comment: can you post a link to your website?

Comment: What errors do you see in the browser's console?

Comment: Why are you keeping the files in the .vscode folder? That's a hidden directory that holds configuration etc

Comment: @j08691 there were no errors. The page is set up on a local host server. I want to change the color of my fond and it won't change to the color that I want. I even tried doing the <style> inside my html to see if it would work and it did, but it won't work if I import it from an external file.

Comment: @DCR it is a local host server

Comment: @AnnaTopp — You need to debug this. Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Console. Are any errors reported? Look in the Network tab. Find the request for the CSS. Does it get a 200 OK status on the response? Is the Content-Type on the response correct? Is the body correct? Does anything else look out of place?

Comment: The `.vscode` directory is where VSCode keeps its settings files for a project. It's a bizarre place to put HTML and CSS files.

Comment: @Quentin okay, yes, thank you, I do have an error saying that it did not apply the css file because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type. (whatever that means lol)

Comment: @AnnaTopp — It means that your server says the CSS file is an HTML document and not a CSS file. Either it is also a 404 error page (which the Network tab should make clear) or your HTTP server is misconfigured.

Comment: @Quentin thanks, i fixed it